# Doownload large files (>300MB) using post method in Angular and Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to enable a download button using angular and Node. I am using the POST method to do it as I have to take the file name in real time and download that file. 
Below is my code

Node Controller :

```
app.post('/api3',function(req,res,next){
    var selectedFileName = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    var fileName = selectedFileName
    var filePath ='absolute path'
    var downloadFile = filePath+fileName+'.csv';
    res.download(downloadFile,fileName1,function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log("Success");
      }
      else{
        console.log("Something");
      }
    });
  });
```

Download

Angular Code :

```
var fileNameJSON = {id1:fileName};

      $http.post('/api3',fileNameJSON)
            .success(function (data)
            {
             if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
               var blob = new Blob([data]);  
               window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
              } 
              else {
                  var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
                  anchor.css({display: 'none'}); // Make sure it's not visible
                  angular.element(document.body).append(anchor);

                  anchor.attr({
                      href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
                      target: '_blank',
                      download: fileName
                  })[0].click();
                $timeout(function(){
                  anchor.remove();
                },5000);
                 //remove();
              };
             })
            .error(function (data)
            {
                console.log("Download Error!!");
            });
```

The above code works fine for small files (upto 2MB) But I need to download larger files.

PS: I am not from web development background

Comment: What's the question? Any error message ?

Comment: If I am downloading large files (>2MB) I am getting download failed -network error.
The question is what is to be needed to download large files (>300MB) in the above code setup

Comment: Please add your full network error log.

Comment: I m also facing same problem. Anyone have solution